# how to give a user permission in samba share?

Tags: networking, permissions, samba, file-sharing

i have created a samba server as following

```
[global]
workgroup = workgroup
server string= samba server %v
dns proxy = no
netbios name = nas
map to guest = bad user
security = user
[rc]
comment=anything
path= /home/egytich/rc
valid users = @sambashare
browsable = yes
writable = yes
read only = no
guest ok = no
create mask = 0775
```

And then i created new user "asd" using user account in system setting, and i made a password, Then using terminal i added that user to samba by the code `sudo sambapasswd -a asd` and used the same password i used when i created it, Also i did chmod and chown to sambashare but on windows client, i can see NAS, the server i made but when i click it it ask for password which is good, When i put "asd" and the password it says no permission , if i put wrong password it go back to let me enter the correct password again, what is my mistake here?

Comment: Plz help even with a link, i have been lost on this in the past 4 days and about to give up all linux

Comment: Restarting the samba server after making config changes is agood idea. For 14.04, run `sudo service smbd restart`.

Comment: @mikewhatever     i always do using this code and even i restart the whole system, its some thing wrong i am doing in the permission part at chmod and chown i need to understand what is this for

Comment: How about something with your `valid users`? Have you looked at this site yet? https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/using_samba/ch09.html I bet you have but there's the link to user additions. Give it another read.

Comment: There is mistake in share section: its `browseable = yes` not `browsable`

Comment: Nice catch, @Taavi

Comment: @Taavi  on the config file i had the correct spelling , on the question i had to retype the whole thing ,not copy paste , since its different PC, that was   ur suggestion in my previous question, i did new share in home directly as u see here and it still not opens, when i go to in windows client, i see NAS in network places, and when i try to open it asks for username and password, no matter what i put ,it doesn't work, i tried samba user and password , then i tried original username and password of the Linux machine and i always get u have no permission

Comment: Please provide results of following commands `groups asd`, `ls -l /home/egytich/rc`

Answer (score 0):

I would try explicitly stating your `valid users`:

```
valid users = asd your_username another_user
```

Another option (workaround?) would be `guest okay = yes` but I think that may not allow root privileges.

Comment: @P Smith   i tried to put guest is ok , but no luck , its the permission and i cant find good page explain it, and groups , i need to know how to check on my user if its under which group and how to cheack which group has permission to access remotely

Comment: `groups asd` shows groups for asd , `ls -l /home/egytich/rc` shows user, group and permissions